# Does Mysql server start before windows login?

Tags: mysql

I have `MYSQL` installed in my `Windows` system. If I just turn on the system and leave it at the Windows Login screen without logging in, I'm still able to access the `MYSQL` DB from a remote system by knowing the IP. 
Is this normal? Does `MYSQL` begin running even before login? Or is remote login somewhat different?

Comment: it depends which user you use for running your Database service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually a windows service, and that indeed starts before you login.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MySQL service will start when Windows started and you can connect any MySQL hosted system on the network knowing IpAddress OR System Name.

If you want to block connecting your MySQL DB, ref: [this link](http://www.greensql.com/content/mysql-security-best-practices-hardening-mysql-tips)